# A map class based on an AVL tree

Tags: c++, c++11, hash-map

Here's an implementation of a class which is similar to `std::map`, but it's not a complete/identical implementation.

I know C pretty well, but am a beginner with C++, so it took me some time to figure out a couple of things, e.g. how to implement an iterator. For now, the iterator only goes forward, because I didn't figure out how to implement `end()` for a bidirectional iterator without much code complication.

Also, I wrote the code in two days, and haven't tested it yet. It seems to work for simple cases, but it's very possible that there are bugs lurking around.

The code was written with the following in mind:

- The priority is the following: time/storage complexity > code simplicity > performance. There are a couple of places which can be obviously improved in terms of performance, such as the copy constructor, but I'm not sure that's possible without enlarging the code by 50% or so.
- No usage of `STL`.

### type_choose.h

```
#ifndef TYPE_CHOOSE_H
#define TYPE_CHOOSE_H

template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct type_choose { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct type_choose < false, T, F > { typedef F type; };

#endif // TYPE_CHOOSE_H
```

### avl_map.h

```
#ifndef AVL_MAP_H
#define AVL_MAP_H

#include <cassert>
#include "type_choose.h"

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class avl_map {
private:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Vertex type

    struct vertex {
        vertex *parent;
        vertex *left, *right;
        int height;

        KEY key;
        VALUE value;

        vertex(const KEY &init_key, const VALUE &init_value) :
            key(init_key), value(init_value) {}
    };

public:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Exceptions

    class exception {};
    class key_does_not_exist : public exception {};
    class key_already_exists : public exception {};

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Iterator

    template<bool is_const_iterator = true>
    class const_noconst_iterator {
    private:
        typedef typename type_choose<is_const_iterator, const avl_map *, avl_map *>::type DataStructurePointerType;
        typedef typename type_choose<is_const_iterator, const vertex *, vertex *>::type VertexPointerType;
        typedef typename type_choose<is_const_iterator, const VALUE &, VALUE &>::type ValueReferenceType;

    public:
        const_noconst_iterator(VertexPointerType ptr) : m_vertex_ptr(ptr) {
        }

        const_noconst_iterator(const const_noconst_iterator<false> &other) : m_vertex_ptr(other.m_vertex_ptr) {
        }

        const_noconst_iterator &operator=(const const_noconst_iterator<false> &other) {
            m_vertex_ptr = other.m_vertex_ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const const_noconst_iterator &other) const {
            return m_vertex_ptr == other.m_vertex_ptr;
        }

        bool operator!=(const const_noconst_iterator &other) const {
            return !(*this == other);
        }

        ValueReferenceType operator*() {
            return m_vertex_ptr->value;
        }

        const_noconst_iterator &operator++() {
            assert(m_vertex_ptr);
            m_vertex_ptr = get_next_vertex(m_vertex_ptr);
            return *this;
        }

        const_noconst_iterator operator++(int) {
            // Use operator++()
            const const_noconst_iterator old(*this);
            ++(*this);
            return old;
        }

        // Make const_noconst_iterator<true> a friend class of const_noconst_iterator<false> so
        // the copy constructor can access the private member variables.
        friend class const_noconst_iterator<true>;

        const KEY &key() {
            return m_vertex_ptr->key;
        }

        ValueReferenceType value() {
            return m_vertex_ptr->value;
        }

    private:
        VertexPointerType m_vertex_ptr; // store a reference to the map
    };

    typedef const_noconst_iterator<false> iterator;
    typedef const_noconst_iterator<true> const_iterator;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Functions

    avl_map() {}
    avl_map(const avl_map &other) {
        for(auto it = other.cbegin(); it != other.cend(); ++it) {
            insert_last(it.key(), it.value());
        }
    }
    ~avl_map() {
        clear();
    }
    avl_map &operator=(const avl_map &other) {
        clear();
        for(auto it = other.cbegin(); it != other.cend(); ++it) {
            insert_last(it.key(), it.value());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const avl_map &other) const {
        auto other_it = other.cbegin();
        if(other_it == other.cend()) {
            return cbegin() == cend();
        }

        for(auto it = cbegin(); it != cend(); ++it) {
            if(other_it == other.cend()) {
                return false;
            }

            if(it.key() != other_it.key()) {
                return false;
            }

            if(it.value() != other_it.value()) {
                return false;
            }

            ++other_it;
        }

        return other_it == other.cend();
    }
    bool operator!=(const avl_map &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(m_first);
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(nullptr);
    }
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return const_iterator(m_first);
    }
    const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator(nullptr);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return begin();
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return end();
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return cbegin() == cend();
    }
    size_t size() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    // Throws if key doesn't exist.
    VALUE &at(const KEY &key) {
        iterator it = find(key);
        if(it == end()) {
            throw key_does_not_exist();
        }

        return *it;
    }
    const VALUE &at(const KEY &key) const {
        const_iterator it = find(key);
        if(it == cend()) {
            throw key_does_not_exist();
        }

        return *it;
    }

    // Exception is thrown if key already exists.
    iterator insert(const KEY &key, const VALUE &value) {
        bool exists;
        iterator it = insert(key, value, exists);
        if(exists) {
            throw key_already_exists();
        }

        return it;
    }
    iterator insert(const KEY &key, const VALUE &value, bool &exists) {
        vertex *v = try_to_find(m_root, key);
        if(v && key == v->key) {
            exists = true;
            return iterator(v);
        }

        exists = false;
        return insert_at(v, key, value);
    }
    // The following functions optimize the insertion time if the inserted
    // key is lower/greater than all existing keys.
    // Exception is thrown if key already exists.
    iterator insert_first(const KEY &key, const VALUE &value) {
        if(m_first && !(key < m_first->key)) {
            return insert(key, value); // unoptimized insert
        }

        return insert_at(m_first, key, value);
    }
    iterator insert_last(const KEY &key, const VALUE &value) {
        if(m_last && !(key > m_last->key)) {
            return insert(key, value); // unoptimized insert
        }

        return insert_at(m_last, key, value);
    }

    bool erase(const KEY &key) {
        vertex *v = try_to_find(m_root, key);
        if(!v || key != v->key) {
            return false;
        }

        erase_vertex(v);
        return true;
    }
    void clear() {
        delete_all_recursive(m_root);
        m_root = m_first = m_last = nullptr;
        m_size = 0;
    }

    iterator find(const KEY &key) {
        vertex *v = try_to_find(m_root, key);
        if(!v || key != v->key) {
            return end();
        }

        return iterator(v);
    }
    const_iterator find(const KEY &key) const {
        vertex *v = try_to_find(m_root, key);
        if(!v || key != v->key) {
            return cend();
        }

        return const_iterator(v);
    }

private:
    vertex *m_root = nullptr;
    vertex *m_first = nullptr, *m_last = nullptr;
    size_t m_size = 0;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Helper functions

    // Returns the vertex with the next larger key.
    static vertex *get_next_vertex(vertex *v) {
        if(v) {
            if(v->right) {
                v = v->right;
                while(v->left) {
                    v = v->left;
                }
            } else if(v->parent) {
                vertex *prev_ptr = v;
                v = v->parent;
                while(v && v->right == prev_ptr) {
                    prev_ptr = v;
                    v = v->parent;
                }
            } else {
                v = nullptr; // we reached the end
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    static const vertex *get_next_vertex(const vertex *v) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/123995
        return const_cast<const vertex *>(get_next_vertex(const_cast<vertex *>(v)));
    }

    void swap_vertex_locations(vertex *v1, vertex *v2) {
        // swap child/parent pointers
        vertex *parent1 = v1->parent;
        vertex *parent2 = v2->parent;

        if(parent1) {
            if(parent1->left == v1) {
                parent1->left = v2;
            } else {
                assert(parent1->right == v1);
                parent1->right = v2;
            }
        } else {
            assert(m_root == v1);
            m_root = v2;
        }
        v1->parent = parent2;

        if(parent2) {
            if(parent2->left == v2) {
                parent2->left = v1;
            } else {
                assert(parent2->right == v2);
                parent2->right = v1;
            }
        } else {
            assert(m_root == v2);
            m_root = v1;
        }
        v2->parent = parent1;

        // swap left/right pointers and height

        vertex *left1 = v1->left;
        vertex *right1 = v1->right;
        int height1 = v1->height;
        vertex *left2 = v2->left;
        vertex *right2 = v2->right;
        int height2 = v2->height;

        if(left1) {
            left1->parent = v2;
        }
        if(right1) {
            right1->parent = v2;
        }
        v1->left = left2;
        v1->right = right2;
        v1->height = height2;

        if(left2) {
            left2->parent = v1;
        }
        if(right2) {
            right2->parent = v1;
        }
        v2->left = left1;
        v2->right = right1;
        v2->height = height1;
    }

    // Tries to find the value with the given key, starting from the given
    // vertex down the tree. If not found, returns the latest vertex in the
    // search path.
    static vertex *try_to_find(vertex *v, const KEY &key) {
        if(!v) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        while(key != v->key) {
            vertex *v_next;

            if(key < v->key) {
                v_next = v->left;
            } else {
                v_next = v->right;
            }

            if(!v_next) {
                return v; // not found, return latest vertex
            }

            v = v_next;
        }

        return v;
    }

    iterator insert_at(vertex *v, const KEY &key, const VALUE &value) {
        vertex *v_new = new vertex(key, value);
        v_new->parent = v;
        v_new->left = v_new->right = nullptr;
        v_new->height = 0;

        if(v) {
            if(key < v->key) {
                assert(!v->left);
                v->left = v_new;
                if(m_first == v) {
                    m_first = v_new;
                }
            } else {
                assert(key > v->key);
                assert(!v->right);
                v->right = v_new;
                if(m_last == v) {
                    m_last = v_new;
                }
            }
        } else {
            assert(!m_root && !m_first && !m_last && m_size == 0);
            m_root = m_first = m_last = v_new;
        }

        m_size++;

        rebalance_from_vertex(v);

        return iterator(v_new);
    }

    void erase_vertex(vertex *v) {
        if(v->left && v->right) {
            vertex *swap_with = get_next_vertex(v);
            assert(swap_with);

            swap_vertex_locations(v, swap_with);
            assert(!v->left || !v->right);
        }

        vertex *parent = v->parent;
        vertex *next = nullptr;

        if(v->left) {
            next = v->left;
        } else if(v->right) {
            next = v->right;
        }

        if(next) {
            next->parent = parent;
        }

        if(v == m_root) {
            assert(!parent);
            m_root = next;
        } else if(parent->left == v) {
            parent->left = next;
        } else {
            assert(parent->right == v);
            parent->right = next;
        }

        if(m_first == v) {
            if(next) {
                m_first = next;
                while(m_first->left) {
                    m_first = m_first->left;
                }
            } else {
                m_first = parent;
            }
        }

        if(m_last == v) {
            if(next) {
                m_last = next;
                while(m_last->right) {
                    m_last = m_last->right;
                }
            } else {
                m_last = parent;
            }
        }

        delete v;
        m_size--;

        rebalance_from_vertex(parent);
    }

    void rebalance_from_vertex(vertex *v) {
        if(!v) {
            return;
        }

        int balance_factor = calculate_balance_factor(v);
        int prev_height = v->height;

        if(balance_factor == 2) {
            int left_balance_factor = calculate_balance_factor(v->left);
            if(left_balance_factor >= 0) {
                v = rotate_left_left(v);
            } else {
                v = rotate_left_right(v);
            }
        } else if(balance_factor == -2) {
            int right_balance_factor = calculate_balance_factor(v->right);
            if(right_balance_factor <= 0) {
                v = rotate_right_right(v);
            } else {
                v = rotate_right_left(v);
            }
        } else {
            assert(balance_factor >= -1 && balance_factor <= 1);
            invalidate_height(v);
        }

        if(v->height != prev_height) {
            rebalance_from_vertex(v->parent);
        }
    }

    static int calculate_balance_factor(const vertex *v) {
        int balance_factor = 0;
        if(v->left) {
            balance_factor += 1 + v->left->height;
        }
        if(v->right) {
            balance_factor -= 1 + v->right->height;
        }
        return balance_factor;
    }

    vertex *rotate_right(vertex *v) {
        vertex *parent = v->parent;
        vertex *left = v->left;
        vertex *left_right = left->right;

        if(!parent) {
            assert(v == m_root);
            m_root = left;
        } else if(parent->left == v) {
            parent->left = left;
        } else {
            assert(parent->right == v);
            parent->right = left;
        }
        left->parent = parent;
        left->right = v;

        v->parent = left;
        v->left = left_right;
        if(left_right) {
            left_right->parent = v;
        }

        invalidate_height(v);
        invalidate_height(left);

        return left;
    }

    vertex *rotate_left(vertex *v) {
        vertex *parent = v->parent;
        vertex *right = v->right;
        vertex *right_left = right->left;

        if(!parent) {
            assert(v == m_root);
            m_root = right;
        } else if(parent->right == v) {
            parent->right = right;
        } else {
            assert(parent->left == v);
            parent->left = right;
        }
        right->parent = parent;
        right->left = v;

        v->parent = right;
        v->right = right_left;
        if(right_left) {
            right_left->parent = v;
        }

        invalidate_height(v);
        invalidate_height(right);

        return right;
    }

    vertex *rotate_left_left(vertex *v) {
        return rotate_right(v);
    }

    vertex *rotate_right_right(vertex *v) {
        return rotate_left(v);
    }

    vertex *rotate_left_right(vertex *v) {
        rotate_left(v->left);
        return rotate_right(v);
    }

    vertex *rotate_right_left(vertex *v) {
        rotate_right(v->right);
        return rotate_left(v);
    }

    static void invalidate_height(vertex *v) {
        int left_height = v->left ? v->left->height : -1;
        int right_height = v->right ? v->right->height : -1;

        v->height = 1 + ((left_height > right_height) ? left_height : right_height);
    }

    static void delete_all_recursive(vertex *v) {
        if(v) {
            delete_all_recursive(v->right);
            delete_all_recursive(v->left);
            delete v;
        }
    }
};

#endif // AVL_MAP_H
```

Comment: This look strange ``class exception {};``. Why not ``std::exception``?

Comment: Yes, I also use a `type_choose` instead of `std::conditional`. That's because one of the constraints is not to use `STL` at all, as mentioned in the post.